# ApiPlatform - how to modify swagger to show valid Json:API format?

Tags: api-platform.com, symfony6

I tried to use Symfony 6.3 + ApiPlatform v3.1.13 with jsonapi format, everything works but I have some issues with swagger.

Documentation bodies/responses are generated for plain json format eg:

```
{
  "id": 0,
  "username": "string",
  "email": "string"
}
```

not for [json:api](https://jsonapi.org/) format. It should be something like:

```
{
  "data": {
    "type": "string",
    "attributes": {
      "id": 0,
      "username": "string",
      "email": "string"
    }
  }
}
```

Unfortunately I couldn't find any informations about this in ApiPlatform documentation, maybe I just misconfigured something? Thanks in advance for any tip how I can overcome this issue!

Comment: Api PLatform support via default json plain or json-ld
https://api-platform.com/docs/core/extending-jsonld-context/
but your json:api is not an RFC. For your issue check hydration chapter. https://symfonycasts.com/screencast/api-platform/json-ld?cid=apip